# sscanf return the right number of arguments even if the last one is a wrong input

Tags: c, scanf

So I have this part of code for reading some infos from a string:

```
  fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
  ...
  else if((sscanf(line, "%s %s %lf %d ", name, id, &price, &qnt ) != 4) ||
                                                    (strlen(name) > 49) || 
                                                    (strlen(id) > 4)){
 ...
```

The problem is that when I insert a input like this:

```
somename 123A 12 12a
```

Which is a wrong input because `12a` isn't a `int`, `sscanf` returns 4 so the execution continues.

If I insert a input like this:

```
somename 123A 12a 123
```

It works fine.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue ? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: As far as `scanf` is concerned, `12a` is the int 12, delimited by an `a`, and I don't think you can tell it to do more stringent validation. If you want more control over your input parsing, you'll probably have to do it yourself instead of using `scanf`, quite simply. It's not overly difficult to do so, using `fgets`.

Comment: You need to make more sophisticated input checks :). There is no other easy way I afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the string with `sscanf` this way:

```
char name[50];
char id[5];
double price;
int qnt;
char c;
if (sscanf(line, "%49s%4s%lf%d %c", name, id, &price, &qnt, &c) != 4) {
    // invalid input
}
```

- if one of the fields cannot be parsed, the return value will be less than 4.
- if there is extra input at the end, the `%c` will skip trailing spaces and successfully convert the extra character into `c` and the return value will be `5`.

Answer (score 1):

The output you received is correct. This is a standard behaviour of the sscanf() function. What you need to understand is that scanf() is a pattern matching function, not a function to read in multiple arguments (although it does that too).

For example,

```
scanf("[%d][%d][%d]", &a, &b, &c)
```

Will expect an input in the form [10][20][30]

How scanf() works is that it reads in one character at a time, tries to match the pattern with it and when the pattern is violated, put the value received in the corresponding variable and put back the extra character (that violated the pattern) back onto the input stream.

So in your case, when you give input as:

```
somename 123A 12 12a
```

the last 12a will be processed char by char and when a is encountered, it will put the value received to that instant (12) and put it inside the designated variable.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently discovered a format specification that I had never seen before.  It is '%n'.  What it returns is the character count processed to that point.  You can use this as the final specifier and it will return a -1 if not all the characters to that point were processed.

sscanf(line, "%s %s %lf %d%n", name, id, &price, &qnt, &charsScanned );
if (charsScanned > 0) {...} // valid input

Although I really like [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266960/925592)'s solution above, too!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go beyond `scanf` and tokenize your input on whitespace, then check each token to validate that it meets your expectations. As with most programming tasks, this is best broken down into chunks. So we can use [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) to get an array of tokens.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t basic_parse(char *src, size_t max, char *dest[max]);

int main() {
    char string[] = "hello world  foo bar   baz 1234";
    char *parsed[4];
    size_t n = basic_parse(string, sizeof(parsed)/sizeof(*parsed), parsed);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", parsed[i]);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        free(parsed[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

size_t basic_parse(char *src, size_t max, char *dest[max]) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char *temp = strtok(src, " ");
    if (temp == NULL) return 0;

    dest[i] = strdup(temp);

    for (
      i = 1; 
      i < max && (temp = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL; 
      ++i
    ) {
        dest[i] = strdup(temp);
    }

    return i;
}
```

This will print:

```
hello
world
foo
bar
```

You could feed this a string retrieved using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) just as easily. You then simply need to check if each element can be parsed as the expected type of data using functions like [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).